# iphone method return NSString returns nothing

Tags: iphone, methods, nsstring

I am trying to understand how to return a NSString.  The method checks the database field and returns "" or the value

What am I doing wrong?

```
- (NSString *) GetText:(char*) FieldName  compiledStatement:(sqlite3_stmt*)  cs {
    char *c = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(cs,  [self get_column_index:cs zName:FieldName] ) ;

    if (c != NULL)  return  (NSString *)c; else return @"";
}
```

calling the method:

```
User = [self GetText:"Name" compiledStatement:compiledStatement];
```

User is

```
NSString *User;
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your return line for

```
if (c != NULL)
    return [NSString stringWithCString:c encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

return @""
```